# how to import lead into netsuite from salesforce

Tags: integration

I am trying to import lead into netsuite from salesforce. How can i achieve it is their any way to get this process done. Please guide me is their any way to do.

Answer (score 3):

I have no experience with Netsuite, but it looks like there is an [API for Netsuite](http://www.netsuite.com/portal/platform/developer/suitetalk.shtml). What I'd so is read up on the documentation for the API and then write some code in Apex that posts the data to the NetSuite API. The approach I'd take would vary depending on how the API works. If you can post multiple leads to Netsuite in a single call, then you could write a trigger with an @future method to post the leads over. If you can only do one lead ata time, then I would lean towards batch apex because you'd quickly hit the callout limits.

More reading: [Apex Web Services and Callouts](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts)

Comment: WSDL2Apex :  Netsuite Application has a WSDL called Suite Talk which you can upload to salesforce and generate the apex classes though you can exchange the data between salesforce and netsuite.

Answer (score 2):

WSDL2Apex :  Netsuite Application has a WSDL called Suite Talk which you can upload to salesforce and generate the apex classes though you can exchange the data between salesforce and netsuite.

Netsuite WSDL can be downloaded here:

http://www.netsuite.com/portal/developers/resources/suitetalk-documentation.shtml

HTPP Callouts:

You can build a custom API in salesforce using apex with @RestResource and expose this URL for Netusite application to make a HTTP Call from them annd they can make the changes on their end using the Suitescript.